# python dynamic execution with threadpoolexecutor

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I am dynamically loading modules and trying to execute the class they contain:

```
class Test(Services):
    def __init__(self):
        Services.__init__(self)

    def start(self):
        print('start')


services_path = 'services'
s = 'test'
instance = getattr(importlib.import_module(services_path + '.' + s), s.title())

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    tmp = executor.submit(instance.start)
    print(tmp.result())
```

But when executing i receive the error:

```
TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: looks kinda like you may not be actually creating an instance, but rather getting a classattr.. you could tell by stepping through with a debugger and query what `instance` is before the with clause.

Comment: as a side note, dynamically loading modules can get you into trouble pretty quickly.. keep in mind the full structure of how imports are done (caching, etc..) I'm not saying it's wrong to do because the functionality is provided in the standard library. I'm just saying it's usually possible to re-factor a little bit and end up with a much simpler structure using more traditional imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the `instance` object, I think it might be only a `type`/`class` object not a `Test` object ... thous you are trying to invoke the method without having instantiated the object

So you you should either instantiate the "instance"

```
instance = getattr(importlib.import_module(services_path + '.' + s), s.title())()
```

or try something like

```
# keep "instance" as is
instance = getattr(importlib.import_module(services_path + '.' + s), s.title())
# and
def _instance_start(instance_class):
    return instance_class().start
executor.submit(_instance_start(instance))
```